# Weird syntax error in a simple code in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

There is a weird syntax error in this code. I don't understand it or any of the errors.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
class Tree {
public:
    Node* root;
    void InputTree() {
        int n, father;
        int nd;
        int child;
        char dir;
        std::cin >> n;
        int** tree = new int* [n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            std::cin >> nd;
            tree[i] = new int[3];
            tree[i][0] = nd;
            tree[i][1] = -1;
            tree[i][2] = -1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            std::cin >> father >> child >> dir;
            if (dir == 'L')
                tree[father][1] = child;
            else
                tree[father][2] = child;
        }
        Initialize(tree, 0);
    }
private:
    void Initialize(int** tree, int headIndex) {
        if (headIndex != -1) {
            root->value = tree[headIndex][0];
            root->right_tree->Initialize(tree, tree[headIndex][2]);
            root->left_tree->Initialize(tree, tree[headIndex][1]);
        }
    }
};
class Node {
public:
    int value;
    Tree* left_tree;
    Tree* right_tree;
};
```

This is the build output of Visual Studio:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: CppMainProject, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>CppMainProject.cpp
1>tstream.h(5,6): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
1>tstream.h(5,6): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>tstream.h(5,12): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>tstream.h(33,4): error C2065: 'root': undeclared identifier
1>tstream.h(34,4): error C2065: 'root': undeclared identifier
1>tstream.h(35,4): error C2065: 'root': undeclared identifier
1>Done building project "CppMainProject.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: I'll bet you could remove 95% of that code and still get the error.

Comment: `Node` has to be moved above `Tree`

Comment: It's usually worth [trying another compiler](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/r33a6dEYf) when you get an error you don't understand. Different compilers do better in different situations.

Comment: And then `Tree` has to be forward-declared (`class Tree;`) before `Node`: you're using class names before they are known to the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In lines like `root->value = tree[headIndex][0];`, you are trying to use the `Node` class before you have told the compiler what that class is. You *can* declare variables as pointers to classes before their *full* definition (but you need a [forward declaration of the class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) to do so) but you can't dereference such pointers until after the full class definition has been provided.

In your code, you can move the definition of the `Node` class to *before* the `Tree` class; but then, as that uses `Tree` pointers, you have to provide a forward declaration that `Tree` is a class.

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class Tree; // Forward declaration that this is a class...

class Node {
public:
    int value;
    Tree* left_tree; // ... so we can now declare pointers to "Tree"
    Tree* right_tree;
};

class Tree {
public:
    Node* root; // We can declare a pointer 
    void InputTree()
    {
    // ... and then the rest of your code as is ...
```

Some worthwhile reading: [When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/553682/10871073)

Comment: This is the best answer so far. It requires fewer changes to the code than the other two suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, but when i did it it says 'Access violance writing' or something like the line `root->value = tree[headIndex][0]`

Comment: @MoatazCraft That's likely because you haven't properly initialized your `Node` member. But that's really a separate question, and you haven't shown the code where you actually use the classes, so I can't really offer anything more, here. Maybe think about how you're setting up your `Tree` and `Node` allocations and, if you still have issues, ask a new question.

Comment: ... most probably, though, you'll want a constructor for your `Tree` class that allocates something for the `root` member to point to ... you can't dereference an uninitialized (or null) pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`Node` is still not defined when you declare `root`. Try to move Node Class  inside Tree class, and I recommend you changing it to struct as folowing:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
class Tree {
public:

    void InputTree() {
        int n, father;
        int nd;
        int child;
        char dir;
        std::cin >> n;
        int** tree = new int* [n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            std::cin >> nd;
            tree[i] = new int[3];
            tree[i][0] = nd;
            tree[i][1] = -1;
            tree[i][2] = -1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            std::cin >> father >> child >> dir;
            if (dir == 'L')
                tree[father][1] = child;
            else
                tree[father][2] = child;
        }
        Initialize(tree, 0);
    }
private:
    struct Node {
        int value;
        Tree* left_tree;
        Tree* right_tree;
    };
    Node* root;
    void Initialize(int** tree, int headIndex) {
        if (headIndex != -1) {
            root->value = tree[headIndex][0];
            root->right_tree->Initialize(tree, tree[headIndex][2]);
            root->left_tree->Initialize(tree, tree[headIndex][1]);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to all be in one file, forward declare `Node` and move the definition of `Tree::Initialize(...)` after the definition of `Node`. Or just forward declare `Node` and use the typical .h file / .cpp file split.

Single file versions goes like this:

```
class Node;  // <= this is a forward declaration...

class Tree {
public:
    Node* root;
    void InputTree() {
        // ....
    }
private:
    void Initialize(int** tree, int headIndex);
};

class Node {
public:
    int value;
    Tree* left_tree;
    Tree* right_tree;
};

void Tree::Initialize(int** tree, int headIndex)
{
    // ...
}
```